# Retrieve images with a given name and a number of 4 digits at the end

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa

I am trying to retrieve all images that starts with a given name and ends with a 4 digit number, example:

> a0001.png a0002.png a0003.png

What i have is:

```
NSArray *imageNames = [files filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", @"a0001.png"]];
```

How can i change the NSPredicate to match all numbers at the end? like string[0-9]{4}.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression with NSPredicate.

The below should match your criteria.

```
NSString *predicateString = @"SELF MATCHES '[a-zA-Z]+\d{4}.png'";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];
```